# C# + Powershell. Как остановить выполнение запущенного приложения на удаленной машине?

Tags: c#, powershell

Есть Web-интерфейс на MVC. В интерфейсе есть возможность запуска приложений на удаленной машине. С запуском проблем нет, все запускается и работает, но как остановить запущенное приложение или сессию powershell?

При запуске приложения создается Runspace и Pipeline - они записываются в соответствующий List. Если с Web-интерфейса приходит request на остановку приложения, то берутся данные из List и дальше у элемента Pipeline вызывается метод Stop(), но приложение либо не останавливается, либо запускается заново по непонятной мне причине

Запуск:

```
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
using(Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
{        
   runspace.Open();
   Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
   singleton.AddPipeline(runspace, pipeline, name);
   Command scriptCommand = new Command(scriptFile);
   pipeline.Commands.Add(scriptCommand);
   output.Add(pipeline.Invoke());
}
```

AddPipeline()

```
Pipelines.Add(new PowershellTask // private List<T> Pipelines {get;set;}
{
   PSPipeline = pipeline,
   Name = name
});
```

RemovePipeline()

```
var pipelines = Pipelines.Where(e => e.Name == name).ToList();
foreach(var pipeline in pipelines)
{
   pipeline.PSPipeline.Stop(); // проблема тут, перепробовал и Stop() и StopAsync()
   Pipelines.Remove(pipeline);
}
```

**UPD**

Функционал работает некорректно если было запущено несколько копий приложения, если была запущена только одна копия то все работает корректно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в невнимательности, в коде вместо одного цикла присутствовало два